# How to make wifi scan on resume?

Tags: wireless, suspend, power-management

When I wake my system from sleep I often have to wait a while for the wifi driver to scan and connect to my network.  If I open a terminal window and run "sudo iwlist scan," the network is detected and connected to right away.  How can I make iwlist scan run automatically upon resume?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
    "resume")
    iwlist scan
    ;;
esac
```

Follow these steps:

1. Open a Terminal. 
       Write this command and enter your password when
       prompted: `sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/iwlist_resume`
2. Paste the
       script on the gedit window, save and close.
3. Give the script
       execution permissions: `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/iwlist_resume`